# Specify border colour on Select2 multi-select when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I would like to change the border color of my `select2` on click (onfocus).

I've tried doing it but it changes the border color of the selection as seen below. How can I specify a border color?

```js
$('.sf-multi-select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select or type to search',
  closeOnSelect: false,
});
```

```css
.select2-search__field:focus {
  border: 1px solid #43AEA8 !important;
}

.sf-multi-select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #43AEA8 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="sf-multi-select" placeholder="Type to search" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="17">Choce 1</option>

  <option value="16">Choice 2</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```js
$('.sf-multi-select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select or type to search',
  closeOnSelect: false,
});
```

```css
.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: 1px solid red!important;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="sf-multi-select" placeholder="Type to search" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="17">Choce 1</option>

  <option value="16">Choice 2</option>

</select>
```

So rather than using `:focus`, you should modify their own focus class `.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus`

Answer (score 1):

Just inspect element. I found class  `.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple`. You can specify border colour in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
.select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--focus .select2-selection, .select2-container--bootstrap-5.select2-container--open .select2-selection {
    border-color: #673ab7;
    box-shadow: unset !important;
}

.select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-dropdown .select2-search .select2-search__field:focus {
    border-color: #673ab7;
    box-shadow: unset !important;
}

.select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-dropdown {
    border-color: #673ab7;
}

.select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option.select2-results__option--selected, .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-dropdown .select2-results__options .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true]:not(.select2-results__option--highlighted) {
    background-color: #673ab7;
}
```